# grub2 issues after upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

I just upgraded a cloud server to 14.04 and grub2 going to a grub rescue prompt on boot.

I have attempted to follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

But the system will not boot.

I can do a `ls /` and it displays the /boot directory.  The root partition appears to be set to the correct drive.  When I do a `insmod normal` it gives me `error: file not found`

I am not even seeing a linux.mod or normal.mod files in my grub directory.  I am thinking that the grub install may have failed.

What steps would be recommended to rescue this server?  Again this is on a vmware esx system so booting from a cd is going to be quite complicated.  What files should I have in the grub and boot folder?  What `insmod` command should I be running to set the kernel and boot commands?

Comment: This is the same problem, but this is a cloud server, so booting from a cd is rather tricky. I am looking for which steps to go through to make grab functional from the rescue prompt.

Comment: If the files aren't there, then they aren't there... you will have to boot from something else.

Comment: After jumping through many evil hoops I got a rescue cd working in the cloud and fixed it